# How to correctly redirect all .html URLs except some specific URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I used to have a site with .html URL and I have updated the URLS without the .html extension. There are also some pages where the URL changed. So what I am trying to do is redirect all .html pages to non .html but there are also page that I am trying to redirect to specific URLs (pages where the URLS changed).

I am able to redirect all .html to the pretty permalinks through this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And redirect some single pages to a specific page through this:

```
redirect 301 /xxx/yyy.html /yyy/
```

Both mentioned above works but some redirect rules doesn't work like this:

```
redirect 301 /information/sub-category/65-xxx.html /sub-category/xxx/
redirect 301 /blog/item/i-am-a-post.html /i-am-a-post/
```

Is there something that I need to add more? My current .htaccess file has this:

```
redirect 301 /xxx/yyy.html /yyy/
redirect 301 /information/sub-category/65-xxx.html /sub-category/xxx/
redirect 301 /blog/item/i-am-a-post.html /i-am-a-post/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Edit: I have moved the RewriteCond after the single redirect and it's still doing the same. Cache cleared.**

Comment: No request for `/xxx/yyy.html` will ever get that far - because you redirected _all_ requests that end in `.html` before already ...

Comment: I moved the code that redirects all  .html URL after the 301s but it's still doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ . You can just add the links to redirect and where to redirect and it takes care of everything